# CPU hardware: more cores means lower frequency at some point?

Tags: central-processing-unit, multi-core, frequency

When taking a look at intel processor product list for servers, it seems like there is a correlation between the base frequency and the number of cores.

Take [this list](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/details/processors/xeon/scalable/platinum/products.html), there is no processor with base frequency above 3.6 Ghz and more than 10 cores.
It seems, the more cores the lower the base frequency.

Is there a correlation like that?
If yes, what is the reason for this, e.g., market, physics, costs?

I am not buying any processors, I just stumbled over this seemingly correlation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case is related to heat. More cores mean more heat. Higher frequency mean more heat. But at the end the crystal can transfer limited amount of heat before burn so this is the reason. And the amount is usually indicated as TDP

> Thermal Design Power (TDP) represents the average power, in watts, the
> processor dissipates when operating at Base Frequency with all cores
> active under an Intel-defined, high-complexity workload. Refer to
> Datasheet for thermal solution requirements.

And to quote comments:

> A socket has a TDP. A core has a maximum frequency. Different people
> want either high frequency or more cores (on a wide variety between
> them) - but that does not change the amount of heat out and energy in
> that a socket is designed to handle. So, it is physics.
>
> Add economy: bigger crystals can be created (for more cores on high
> GHz) but this mean less working processors per silicon base (wafer).
> And probability of defect processor increase (because of the size).

Comment: To add: A socket has a TDP. A core has a maximum frequency. Different people want either high frequency or more cores (on a wide variety between them) - but that does not change the amount of heat out and energy in that a socket is designed to handle. So, it is physics.

Comment: @TomTom, and to add economy: bigger crystals can be created (for more cores on high GHz) but this mean less working processors per silicon base (wafer). And probability of defect processor increase (because of the size).

Comment: Yeah, but unless you make new sockets (and thus new motherboards) you are always defined by the TDP of the socket. And making the TDP GENERALLY higher means higher costs for ALL CPU. There simply is no good solution for that.